# Not able to communicate on CAN (NUC472 devkit)

Tags: controller, arm, embedded, can-bus

I am using CAN interface example of normal mode Tx, RX.

I am using the NUMaker-PFM-NUC472 kit.
BSP version is 3.03.00

I have taken reference of CAN normal TX, RX mode example for this.

when the transmission has occurred after that I am getting continuously interrupted with the following print.
EWARN INT

I have dump CAN1 Status register and its value is: 0x61

Also, I have dump CAN1 control register and it's value after init is: 0x06

```
void can_test()
{
    SYS_UnlockReg();
    SYS->GPA_MFPL &= ~(SYS_GPA_MFPL_PA0MFP_Msk | SYS_GPA_MFPL_PA1MFP_Msk);
    SYS->GPA_MFPL |= (SYS_GPA_MFPL_PA0MFP_CAN1_RXD |
    SYS_GPA_MFPL_PA1MFP_CAN1_TXD);
    SYS_LockReg();
    CAN_T *tCAN;
    tCAN = (CAN_T ) CAN1;
    CAN_EnterInitMode(tCAN);
    CLK->APBCLK0 |= CLK_APBCLK0_CAN1CKEN_Msk;
    SYS->IPRST1 |= SYS_IPRST1_CAN1RST_Msk;
    SYS->IPRST1 &= ~SYS_IPRST1_CAN1RST_Msk;
    int32_t i32Err = CAN_Open(tCAN, 1000000, CAN_NORMAL_MODE);
    CAN_CLR_INT_PENDING_BIT(CAN1, ((CAN1->IIDR) -1));
    CAN_EnableInt(CAN1, CAN_CON_IE_Msk | CAN_CON_SIE_Msk);
    NVIC_SetPriority(CAN1_IRQn, (1 << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS) - 2);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN1_IRQn);
    CAN_LeaveInitMode(CAN1);
    STR_CANMSG_T tMsg;
    / Send a 11-bits message */
    tMsg.FrameType= DATA_FRAME;
    tMsg.IdType = CAN_STD_ID;
    tMsg.Id = 0x7FF;
    tMsg.DLC = 2;
    tMsg.Data[0] = 7;
    tMsg.Data[1] = 0xFF;
    CAN_Transmit(tCAN, MSG(0),&tMsg);
}

/*Written IRQ handler as following*/
void CAN1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    printf_debug( "CAN1_IRQHandler %d",CAN1->STATUS);
    uint32_t u8IIDRstatus;
    u8IIDRstatus = CAN1->IIDR;
    if(u8IIDRstatus == 0x00008000) {
    if(CAN1->STATUS & CAN_STATUS_RXOK_Msk)
    {
        CAN1->STATUS &= ~CAN_STATUS_RXOK_Msk;
        printf_debug( "RX OK INT\r\n\r");
    }
    if(CAN1->STATUS & CAN_STATUS_TXOK_Msk)
    {
        CAN1->STATUS &= ~CAN_STATUS_TXOK_Msk;
        printf_debug( "TX OK INT\r\n\r");
    }
    if(CAN1->STATUS & CAN_STATUS_EWARN_Msk) 
    {
        printf_debug( "EWARN INT\n\r");
    }
    if(CAN1->STATUS & CAN_STATUS_BOFF_Msk)
    {
        printf_debug( "BOFF INT\n\r");
    }
    } 
    else if (u8IIDRstatus!=0) 
    {
        if (can_config_internal.can_rx_callback != NULL) 
        {
            printf_debug( "can_config_internal.can_rx_callback");
            can_config_internal.can_rx_callback((nlg_can_module_t)CAN1,
            u8IIDRstatus);
        }
        CAN_CLR_INT_PENDING_BIT(CAN1, ((CAN1->IIDR) -1));
    } 
    else if(CAN1->WU_STATUS == 1) 
    {
        CAN1->WU_STATUS = 0;
    }
}
```

Am I missing any configuration or initialization?

Let me know if you need more detail regarding this

Comment: You can't do debug prints from inside the ISR. By the time you have printed the debug info, all your receiver buffers will be overrun. This is perhaps what happens - you occupy the ISR while printing some status, blocking the MCU from parsing incoming messages, overrunning the buffers. The CAN controller goes error active mode from repeated overruns and you get "error warning". Start by getting this to work with polling, before anything else.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious I should not print or add any delay in the ISR context, But the issue was not due to that. It was some hardware changes I have done


Reference : https://github.com/OpenNuvoton/NUC472_442BSP/issues/7